# Is it possible to delete data from Firebase by invoking servlets using Google App Engine cron jobs?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, cron, firebase

I have developed a simple chat application using AngularJs and Firebase. I have hosted this application on the Google app engine platform. Now, I want to delete the Firebase database containing chat messages on a schedule (every night).

Is there any way to achieve this using a servlet, so that it can be invoked as a cron job? Thanks.

PS: The firebase documentation has been given only for Android and I am new to this. SO, specifically looking for servlet code.

Comment: The answer provided should address your questions in this post.  If you agree that your questions have been answered, please select it so this question may be considered resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question or description what you need assistance with. This answer assumes you'd like a daily cron job to send a request to an App Engine handler which then deletes data from a Firebase database.

From the documentation, Firebase has a [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/). Therefore, data can be added, removed and updated using standard HTTP requests ([`GET`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-get), [`PUT`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-put), [`POST`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-post), [`PATCH`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-patch), [`DELETE`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-delete)). Any application capable of issuing HTTP requests can make changes to the data when [properly authenticated and authorized](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html).

Given your request to use a cron job and Java servlet on App Engine, I'd advise the following:

Define a cron job that issues requests to a specific URL in your `cron.xml`

```
<cron>
  <url>/firebase_cleanup</url>
  <description>Delete all chat messages of the day</description>
  <schedule>every day 23:00</schedule>
</cron>
```

Deploy a servlet that will handle such requests and issue the appropriate HTTP request to Firebase. In your case, it should issue a [`DELETE`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-delete) request. This can be done using [`HttpURLConnection`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet#Using_HttpURLConnection).

```
URL url = new URL("firebase-url-formatted-for-delete-request");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
// Act upon responseCode accordingly
```

Note that the above servlet code does not include the authentication you'll need to issue the `DELETE` request. That will require your Firebase secret or a [generated token](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-token-generation). As I do not have a Firebase account, I cannot test the above so it will likely require some modifications.